# How to format table for resume building?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Please find the expected output blueprint

> [image]

Also, how can we change the width and height of the image ?

> [image]

if we want it to be 3.5 cms by 4.3 cms. on A4 sheet.
Is it possible ?

and MVE below:

```
% LaTeX file for resume 
% This file uses the resume document class (res.cls)

\documentclass{res} 
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in} % increase text height to fit on 1-page 
\usepackage{graphicx}
%for floating figures
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document} 

\sffamily%
{\small\begin{tabular}[c]{l}
  123 Spruce St, Apt 35 \\
  Philadelphia PA 19103
\end{tabular}}\hfill%
{\Large\bfseries\begin{tabular}[c]{c}
  GAYLE LAAKMANN
\end{tabular}}\hfill%
{\small\begin{tabular}[c]{r}
  (555) 555-1212 \\
  gayle@careerup.com
\end{tabular}}%



\quad\parbox{8cm}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item Age:          &     30                 Nationality: CO
    \item Marital status: Single      &      Github: \href{https://github.com/in/xyz/}{github}
    \item Linkedin:         \href{https://linkedin.com/in/xyz/}{linkedIn} & Skype: xyz
\end{itemize}
}
\hfill
\quad\parbox{4cm}{
\hspace{0.75\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{download.jpg}
}                                  
\begin{resume}         

\end{resume}
```

Comment: _Please find the_ what?

Comment: Trying to add expected output image...but not happening

Comment: OK, I've edited it for you, please if this is not what you want, remove and modify.

Comment: You are probably better of using one of the more modern resume classes that to use res